# Affine linear map, finite-dim. reducible rep. but can't be decomopsed as a direct sum of irreducible subreps?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

For $a \in \mathbb{R}^\times$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, let$$g_{a, b} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \text{ }x \mapsto a \cdot x + b$$be an affine linear map. Let$$\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R}) = \{g_{a, b} : a \in \mathbb{R}^\times,\, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$be the group, with respect to composition, of all such maps. My question is, what is an example of a finite-dimensional representation $\rho$ of $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\rho$ is not irreducible but it can not be decomposed as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ by affine maps. If we identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the subset $\{(1,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, the action of $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ extends uniquely to a linear action on $\mathbb{R}^2$, given by
$$
\rho:g_{a,b}\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\b&a\end{array}\right]\in GL_2(\mathbb{R}).
$$
There is a $1$-dimensional subrepresentation $\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. A complementary subrepresentation would need to be $1$-dimensional, and would have to be spanned by a vector $(x,y)$ with $x\neq 0$. We may choose the spanning vector to be of the form $(1,y)$. But $\rho(g_{1,1})(1,y)=(1,y+1)$, and a subspace containing $(1,y)$ and $(1,y+1)$ cannot be $1$-dimensional.

We conclude that $\rho$ is not a direct sum of irreducible representations, because we have found a subrepresentation without a complement.